# hover li and change sibling submenu

Tags: html, css

I need a little help here. I am trying to make a menu with submenu to be open without javascript or jquery (Only css if it is possible).

```
<nav id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link1</a></li>
    <li class="haschildren selected">
    <a>Link2</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">Link2-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link2-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link2-3</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="haschildren">
   <a>Link3</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">Link3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link3-2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

When i have the class selected and page is loaded the .selected .submenu is open. But when i hover the other li that has submenu i want the selected submenu to disappear and the new one appear. In my case i cannot make the selected submenu hidden when hover over Link3 li.
Sorry for my english. To make it clear i would like when hover Link3 the Link2 submenu to become hidden and the Link3 submenu to open. But when hover out from Link3 to return to the default selected. If anyone could help i would appreciate it.

I made an example here. https://jsfiddle.net/ef8zgogr/

Comment: You don't need the `.selected`  classname, because with `:hover` pseudostate you can achieve the whole functionality without changing the classnames.

Comment: I would like the selected.submenu to be open after page is loaded. That's why i use selected class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply a display none to the .submenu's and then on :hover over the parent li (with the class of .hasChildren) change it to display block.

```css
.submenu {display:none}
.selected ul{display:block}

#container:hover li ul{display:none}
#container li:hover ul{display:block}
```

```html
<nav id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link1</a></li>
    <li class="haschildren selected">
    <a>Link2</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">Link2-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link2-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link2-3</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="haschildren">
   <a>Link3</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">Link3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link3-2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: When the page is loaded i would like the selected.submenu to be open. How can i achieve that? and then after each hover return to the original state

Comment: ok - try this -there are two arts to it - the inital state in which the selected ul is shown and the non selected ul is not. Then on the hover over the paent list hides all ul li except for the ul you are hovering over. Then when you leave the #container - it reverts back to the original state.

Answer (score 0):

> But when i hover the other li that has submenu i want the selected
>   submenu to disappear

there is no easy way to toggle close the selected (expanded) submenu when other submenu has been hover (more like radio button) by straight css.